# mysql innodb broken, after hostname change

Tags: mysql, innodb

Gents,
  Have a mysql cluster down right now... in dev, but down nonetheless.  This occurred after a hostname change on both nodes.

```
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock /usr/local/mysql/data/ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock /usr/local/mysql/data/ibdata1, error: 11
```

MyISAM tables load fine...

What do I need to do to get the mysql back in order? thansk!

Comment: What filesystem are these files stored on?

Comment: in dev they are on NFS... mysql user has right to access the log files, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with stale locks on NFS. Try this:

```
/etc/init.d/portmap restart
/etc/init.d/nfslock restart
```

See [this bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47769) and this [success report](http://onaxer.com/blog/blog/2010/06/01/innodb-unable-to-lock-ibdata1-error-37/).

Comment: no go, have tried this already :(

Comment: Then the lock is stuck on the NFS server. You can either restart the lock manager on the server or replace the files with copies of themselves. (`cp foo foo.bak; rm foo; mv foo.bak foo;` -- If paranoid, keep the copies and use 'mv' instead of 'rm'.)